# How to construct a string by reading ip address from a file in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a text file which will have IP Address like this -

```
1.2.3.4
4.5.6.67
9.10.23.40
11.12.3.4
4.15.16.67
19.10.23.40
```

Now I need to read the above text file and construct below sql string for each IP Address - As you can see, only the IP Address portion is changing, apart from that everything is same.

```
insert into some_table (id, ip_address, last_modified_date, customer_name) values (1, '1.2.3.4', dateOf(now()), 'hello')
insert into some_table (id, ip_address, last_modified_date, customer_name) values (1, '4.5.6.67', dateOf(now()), 'hello')
insert into some_table (id, ip_address, last_modified_date, customer_name) values (1, '9.10.23.40', dateOf(now()), 'hello')
insert into some_table (id, ip_address, last_modified_date, customer_name) values (1, '11.12.3.4', dateOf(now()), 'hello')
insert into some_table (id, ip_address, last_modified_date, customer_name) values (1, '4.15.16.67', dateOf(now()), 'hello')
insert into some_table (id, ip_address, last_modified_date, customer_name) values (1, '19.10.23.40', dateOf(now()), 'hello')
```

What is the best way to do this in shell script?

**Update:-**

This is what I have tried -

```
#!/bin/bash
while read host rest; do
    # not sure what should I do here
  EOF
done < ipList.txt
wait
```

I was not able to understand how can I make a sql string after I get the IP Address

Comment: It's not difficult, but what have you tried so far?

Comment: @rendon just updated. Sorry I was too fast in posting the question, didn't copied what I was working on.

Comment: Lots of simple ways to do this. You can use `printf` in bash if you have the IP address already. Check `man printf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your file contains just one column and you are reading two (`read host rest`).

Second, what is dateOf(now()), I mean, is it a bash function?

A possible solution look like so:

```
while read ip; do
    echo "insert into some_table (id, ip_address, last_modified_date, customer_name) values (1, '$ip', dateOf(now()), 'hello')"
done < ipList.txt
```

If `dateOf(now())` is a bash function you might store the result in a variable and then using in the fallowing way:

```
function dateOfNow() {
    echo -n $(date); # Just an example :)
}
while read ip; do
    d=$(dateOfNow)
    echo "insert into some_table (id, ip_address, last_modified_date, customer_name) values (1, '$ip', $d), 'hello')"
done < ipList.txt
```

Example output:

```
insert into some_table (id, ip_address, last_modified_date, customer_name) values (1, '1.2.3.4', Wed Dec 17 15:05:55 CST 2014), 'hello')
insert into some_table (id, ip_address, last_modified_date, customer_name) values (1, '4.5.6.67', Wed Dec 17 15:05:55 CST 2014), 'hello')
insert into some_table (id, ip_address, last_modified_date, customer_name) values (1, '9.10.23.40', Wed Dec 17 15:05:55 CST 2014), 'hello')
insert into some_table (id, ip_address, last_modified_date, customer_name) values (1, '11.12.3.4', Wed Dec 17 15:05:55 CST 2014), 'hello')
insert into some_table (id, ip_address, last_modified_date, customer_name) values (1, '4.15.16.67', Wed Dec 17 15:05:55 CST 2014), 'hello')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
$ while read ip; do printf "insert into some_table (id, ip_address, last_modified_date, customer_name) values (1, '%s', dateOf(now()), 'hello')\n" $ip; done < file
insert into some_table (id, ip_address, last_modified_date, customer_name) values (1, '1.2.3.4', dateOf(now()), 'hello')
insert into some_table (id, ip_address, last_modified_date, customer_name) values (1, '4.5.6.67', dateOf(now()), 'hello')
insert into some_table (id, ip_address, last_modified_date, customer_name) values (1, '9.10.23.40', dateOf(now()), 'hello')
insert into some_table (id, ip_address, last_modified_date, customer_name) values (1, '11.12.3.4', dateOf(now()), 'hello')
insert into some_table (id, ip_address, last_modified_date, customer_name) values (1, '4.15.16.67', dateOf(now()), 'hello')
insert into some_table (id, ip_address, last_modified_date, customer_name) values (1, '19.10.23.40', dateOf(now()), 'hello')
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this :

```
 cat  ipList.txt | xargs -n1 -I % echo  "insert into some_table (id, ip_address, last_modified_date, customer_name) values (1, '%', dateOf(now()), 'hello')"
```

output :

```
insert into some_table (id, ip_address, last_modified_date, customer_name) values (1, '1.2.3.4', dateOf(now()), 'hello')
insert into some_table (id, ip_address, last_modified_date, customer_name) values (1, '4.5.6.67', dateOf(now()), 'hello')
insert into some_table (id, ip_address, last_modified_date, customer_name) values (1, '9.10.23.40', dateOf(now()), 'hello')
insert into some_table (id, ip_address, last_modified_date, customer_name) values (1, '11.12.3.4', dateOf(now()), 'hello')
insert into some_table (id, ip_address, last_modified_date, customer_name) values (1, '4.15.16.67', dateOf(now()), 'hello')
insert into some_table (id, ip_address, last_modified_date, customer_name) values (1, '19.10.23.40', dateOf(now()), 'hello')
```